# How do i use WindsorInstaller across multiple assemblies for registration

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am using Castle Windsor to handle my Dependency Injection and it has been working great up until now.

However, i am now trying to extend my project and add some additional libraries - im now struggling to figure the best way to leverage Castle.

I currently have the following assemblies

MyProject.Interfaces (contains IDBContext interface)
MyProject.BusinessLogic (contains the Castle Windsor implementation)
MyProject.DataAccess (contains implementation of IDBContext)

I currently have an installer called DBContextInstaller and it simply implements the following:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IDBContext>()
                .WithService
                .DefaultInterface()
                .Configure(reg => reg.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
}
```

I now have a new Assembly in this project - lets call it MyProject.UserService and it happens to have a new concrete implementation of IDBContext.

So my question - how can i change my Container.Register statement to have it inspect multiple libraries. NOTE i totally expect to have more and more libraries added to this scenario in the future. I would love for this installer to just find all implementations.

TIA

Comment: If you have multiple implementations of `IDBContext`, which one should the application pick? Or is `MyProject.UserServices` used in another application (thus are you sharing assemblies over multiple applications)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use AllTypes.FromAssemblyInDirectory...

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(folderPath)));
```