# How would I apply an Interceptor to a list of assemblies in a directory?

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

For example an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900680/how-do-i-use-windsorinstaller-across-multiple-assemblies-for-registration) by Mark Seemann
was this:
`container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(folderPath)));`

This would register all assemblies in a given directory, including 3rd party assemblies that I am not interested in.

I only want to register a list of assemblies in a directory, and the second part I am not sure how to do,  is to apply my interceptors to the assemblies in that list.

So I am asking how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but I am thinking something like this:

```
foreach (var referencedAssembly in referencedAssemblies)
            {
                base.BootStrapContainer.Register(
                    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(referencedAssembly)
                           .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
                           .Pick()
                           .Configure(component => component.Interceptors<TracingAspect>()));

            }
```